# I'm trying to install maatwebsite/excel package to my laravel with but got this error

Tags: php, json, excel, laravel, docker-compose

I'm trying to install maatwebsite/excel package to my laravel with this command

`composer require maatwebsite/excel`

but i got this error message instead:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.28, ..., 3.1.30] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.16.* -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.16.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.31, ..., 3.1.x-dev] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.18 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.18.0, 1.19.0, 1.20.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.27 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.16 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.16.0, ..., 1.20.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.26 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.15 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.15.0, ..., 1.20.0].
equirement.
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.15.0, ..., 1.20.0] require ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install 
or enable PHP's gd extension.
    - Root composer.json requires maatwebsite/excel ^3.1 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0, ..., 3.1.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-gd` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require maatwebsite/excel:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require maatwebsite/excel:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

i'm using :
composer version 2.2.1
PHP version 8.0.1
laravel 8.68.1

what caused this???

Comment: As the message states, your system is missing the `php-gd` extension that is a requirement for that package. Install `php-gd` and try again.

Answer (score 3):

The error thrown also gives you the solution, there are some missing packages that the extension requires, just install them separately or allow composer to auto install all with this line:

```
composer require maatwebsite/excel:*
```